# Karate Gatling report - is it possible to avoid url based aggregation?

Tags: karate

I just started to use Karate Gatling for performance tests and facing following problem:

- I have a call for the search and would like to evaluate different types of search depending on the parameter e.G. https://example.com/search/facetedSearch

  - '*'
  - 'keyword1'
  - 'keyword1, keyword2' etc.
    The feature file looks something like this:

    ```
    @performance
    ```

    Feature: Search

    ```
    Background:
      * url 'https://example.com/'

    Scenario Outline: Search -> Simple search for a single word
      Given path '/search/facetedSearch'
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchAreaID] = -1
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchKey] = '<SearchTermSimple>'
      When method post
      Then status 200
      And assert iNumHits >= iNumHitsExpected

      Examples:
        | read('../testData/performanceTestData.csv') |


    Scenario: Search -> Simple search for *
      Given path '/search/facetedSearch'
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchAreaID] = -1
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchKey] = '*'
      When method post
      Then status 200
      And assert iNumHits >= iNumHitsExpected


    Scenario Outline: Search -> Search for multiple words
      Given path '/search/facetedSearch'
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchAreaID] = -1
      And param facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchKey] = '<SearchTermMultiple>'
      When method post
      Then status 200
      And assert iNumHits >= iNumHitsExpected

      Examples:
        | read('../testData/performanceTestData.csv') |
    ```

I would like to evaluate different types of search separately, as the performance is significantly different. What gatling does - it aggregates all different types of search in one result - "POST /search/facetedSearch".
Is there a possibility to let evaluate every type of search individually in one run?

Thanks in advance,
Sergej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, refer the docs on using a custom `nameResolver`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#nameresolver

For your case you should be able to call `req.getParam("facetedSearchAdditionalFilter[searchKey]")[0]` or something similar. Or you could choose to use an additional header.